# Matlab's diary + job scheduler

Tags: matlab, distributed-computing

I want to use diary(‘log.txt’) to create a log file.

The script is run as a Job using createJob()+createTask() or batch().

The log.txt is created, but nothing is written in log.txt.

The test code a.m:

```
c = parcluster;
j = createJob(c);
createTask(j, @b, 0, {});
submit(j);
```

b.m:

```
function [] = b()
    diary off
    delete b.txt
    diary b.txt
    disp('hello')
    diary off
end
```

Is there any convenient method to enable the diary function in a job except this one https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/distcomp/diary.html?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `diary` with a file, jobs submitted using Parallel Computing Toolbox can automatically capture diary output. This output is updated as execution progresses. If you create the job using the [`batch`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/batch.html) command, diary output is captured by default. Here's an example that can demonstrate the diary output being updated:

```
function [] = b()
for ii = 1:10
    fprintf('hello: %d\n', ii);
    pause(2);
end
end
```

And then invoke it like so:

```
j = batch(@b, 0);
wait(j, 'running');
while ~strcmp(j.State, 'finished')
    diary(j)
    pause(2)
end
```

(Note the second input to `batch` is the number of output arguments requested from `b`). This results in output like the following being printed to the command window:

> ```
> Warning: The diary of this batch job might be incomplete because the job is still running. 
> --- Start Diary ---
> hello: 1
> hello: 2
> hello: 3
> hello: 4
>
> --- End Diary ---
> ```

Comment: It is the official solution. However. I think it has limitations. 1. The log file is not written immediately. 2. We need to write some more codes to arrange the jobs.

Finally, I use a similar trick like:
batch(‘T=evalc(…);…;fpritnf(f,T);…’)
At least, I do not need to wait for these unfinished jobs.

Comment: 1. The diary output of a `batch` job is updated as execution progresses, I'll change my answer to demonstrate. 2. Not sure what you mean here.